# How do you implement a button triggering different actions each time it is pressed?

Tags: xcode, uibutton

Just like a video recording button. Starts when pressed, and stops when pressed again.

A little guidance would be very helpful...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you running into trouble? What have you tried that isn't working? What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Actually I don't know how to make the button trigger another action when pressed a second time. Should I write a button state or smt like a loop? I don't have any idea..

Comment: use bool flag to start and stop in button action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a toggle button that shows play / stop something like following will work...

```
-(IBAction) togglePlay:(id)sender{


        if (audioPlayer.playing) {

            [audioPlayer stop];
            [playButton setBackgroundImage:playSoundImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            //set image play

        }else{

            [audioPlayer play];
            [playButton setBackgroundImage:stopSoundImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }


}
```